# Proxy HTTP traffic over SOCKS?

Tags: linux, tunnel, socks-proxy

I used it once before but I can't remember what it was called.

I need to tell my http app to connect to a site but I need to tunnel it through a proxy. Unfortunately the app doesn't support proxies. There is at least one linux app that allows me to say take this addr (localhost:1234) and connect it to target:5678 over SOCKS proxy proxyhost:9012

What software may I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

use proxychains

eg. $ proxychains whatever-program.

ProxyChains allows to run any program through HTTP or SOCKS proxy. This tool forces all connections of given application to follow through user-defined list of proxies.